# Can't add folder www to github repo

Tags: git, github, npm, rust, rust-wasm

I created a rustwasm project following:

```
cargo generate --git https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack-template
wasm-pack build
npm init wasm-app www
```

I've done some work in the `www` folder, but whenever I try to commit to github it doesn't add the `www` folder.
I've checked the git ignores and it isn't ignored anywhere. Anyone know why it won't get added?

This is what [I followed](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/hello-world.html).

Output of `git status`:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   www (modified content)
```

Comment: please try to type `git status --ignored` and check if the `www` folder isn't really ignored

Comment: It isn't in the list

Comment: when you type `git add www` what do happens?

Comment: there is no output, but after checking `git status` it hasn't been added

Comment: you should see the `www` folder in the untracked content or in the tracked (ready to be committed) content. Can you see that?

Comment: I says it is under `Changes not staged to commit`

Comment: try again a `git add www` and see if something changes

Comment: It didn't do anything, the folder shows up in github but it has an arrow through it and it can't be opened. When I pull from it, there is no contents to it either.

Comment: There is a `.git` in `www`, I tried removing it but then I couldn't add the folder to the repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably facing with a submodule.
Your `www` folder is pointing to another git repository.

Please check in Github, if beside the folder name you have an hash, something like: `www @ a773f5e`.

If this is correct, you should have also a file named `.gitmodules` in the root of the project.

You can initialize and clone the submobule repository with the command: `git submodule update --init`

---

**Edit**

This is a **gitlink**.

Typing `git ls-tree HEAD www` you should see the special mode `160000` at the very left. It is recorded from git as a submodule, but it isn't.

To recover you need to:

1. **remove from the index the gitlink**: `git rm --cached www`
   This command won't delete your files or your changes from the disk, just from the git's working index.
2. **delete the `.git` folder**: `rm -fr www/.git`
3. **add the `www` folder to the index**: `git add www`
4. **commit and push**

Now your `www` folder should act as a normal folder.

Comment: I don't have a hash beside the folder, just a white arrow through the icon. There is no `.gitsubmodule` in the root.